# Suggested name for "inflated" tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, solid-geometry, simplex, platonic-solids

What's the name or class of the following tetrahedron-like shape?

[image: Tetrahedron Geometry and related geometries for construction]
[Sketchup Model](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=759c1a31-c3b5-42d5-b138-5e661db05a50)

[WebGL 3D-viewer](https://my.sketchup.com/viewer/3dw?WarehouseModelId=759c1a31-c3b5-42d5-b138-5e661db05a50)

It's apparently some sort of (not strictly convex) shell of a tetrahedron and it's [scaled spherical projection dual](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical_compound_of_two_tetrahedra.png) compound, which both share the same outer cube.

It has some interesting properties, since it's still unfoldable to a flat net, and when used as a projection surface, as in the [Authagraph world map](http://www.authagraph.com/data/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/AG_EN_02.gif) has a less abrupt change in curvature, and therefore less angular distortion than a [regular tetrahedron](https://www.mapthematics.com/ProjectionsList.php?Projection=217).

It's construction can be described of placing 6 intersecting oblique solid bicones with their straight long edge (apex-circle-apex is a straight line normal to the base circle's plane) on the edges of the tetrahedron, and circle centers placed at the centroid.

It's therefore not! constructable from 4 right circular cones placed with apexes on the tetrahedron's vertices.

If the cone base circle is a unit circle, the height of the cone is $\sqrt2$ or double that for the bicone.

The surface is the sum of 6 bicone segments with an angle of 109.5° or  $\cos^{−1}(-\frac13)$ encompassing the edge on the orthogonal circle.

[image: Construction of bicone]

[One of the 6 bi-cones placed on a tetrahedronal edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhiMf.png)

[image]

Note the adjoined cones don't meet at flat surface, but something like 163.5° (~16°) making the shape effectively concave.

[image: concave angle closeup]

A google (image) search for "inflated tetrahedron" hits quite near, yet yields no satisfying mathematical descriptions to me.

Related terms I was able to find so far:

- [Tetrapod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapod_(structure))
- [Triakis tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triakis_tetrahedron) the [Kleeotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleetope) of the Tetrahedron
- [Hyperbolic tetrahedron](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Geometry/Geometry.html) [img](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Geometry/Cirk11b.gif) generated by [Ricci Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_flow)
- It looks alot like this [Tetrahedron Lattice](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/1868535_fig2_FIG-9-A-tetrahedron-lattice-left-is-collapsed-by-application-of-vertex-forces)
- [Combinatorial Polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_combinatorics) of a [Type D Coxeter-associahedra](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~sf34/hedra.htm)
- [Cayley’s Nodal Cubic Surface](http://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2016/08/15/cayleys-nodal-cubic-surface/) thanks [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991946/suggested-name-for-inflated-tetrahedron?noredirect=1#comment4090687_1991946)
- [scanning a sphere with 4 cones](http://opticalengineering.spiedigitallibrary.org/article.aspx?articleid=1352676)
- [These Hot Air Ballons!](http://www.skychariot.com/tetrahedron/)

It apparently doesn't have the properties of a Reuleaux or Meissner tetrahedron, since the plain tetrahedron is still present in the rounded out edges, which are still straight lines between the tetrahedrons vertices.

Can this be generalized for other simplexes?

Comment: I suspect I won't be of much help to you in any case, but ... Did I interpret the illustration correctly: Each triangular face, flat in a normal tetrahedron, are "puffed out" to a non-flat, roundish patch, keeping the triangular outer perimeter straight and flat? Do you have any equations describing this? Especially the .. um.. puffiness of the faces, the distortion, would be interesting to see parametrized.

Comment: I have parametrization yet, just a geometric construction. I'm trying to make sense of the Authagraph process. In my ideal model there would be four intersecting surfaces(cones?) that are created by connection the Tetrahedral tiling of a unit sphere in dual position to a tetrahedron constructed in a unit cube. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#/media/File:Uniform_tiling_332-t2.png

Comment: If they were cones, one could project directly to those four, this sounds way more straightforward than than process described by Authagraph, http://www.authagraph.com/projects/description/%E3%80%90%E4%BD%9C%E5%93%81%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC%E3%80%91%E8%A8%98%E4%BA%8B01/?lang=en and possibly also generalizable to other platonic solids. Prepare for traditional Pinata style world map projections ;)

Comment: I added an interactive 3d view, WebGL required: https://my.sketchup.com/viewer/3dw?WarehouseModelId=759c1a31-c3b5-42d5-b138-5e661db05a50

Comment: A right circular cone ( call it Tetcone for time being) has its semi-vertical angle $ \cot^{-1} \sqrt 2 $ Place the vertices of such 4 Tetcones at the corners of regular tetrahedron so that their axes of symmetry are concurrent forming a union. Is that it? If so the development is a simple vertical development, trisection of a straight angle $\pi$ as a half hexagon.

Comment: I think they can't be right circular cones, since the intersections are circular, while they should be elliptical in right cones. Possibly three joined oblique cones per tetrahedral vertex, each defined by their circular intersection with the dual (or first iteration barycentric subdivision of the tetrahedron), where the normal line connecting circle base and apex is also the edge of the inscribed tetrahedron. So in total 6 oblique bicones are needed.

Comment: Re. your last question: It seems straightforward to generalize this to other simplexes, by defining a bicone for each edge in the same manner. Is there any difficulty with this construction?

Comment: P.S. I believe the contours in the picture are a little misleading -- the shape is actually smooth along the circular arcs, but nonsmooth along the lines (not drawn) joining the tetrahedron vertices to the junctions where the arcs meet. The contours in the figure suggest a slightly different shape, formed by four circular cones emerging from the tetrahedon vertices which meet at the circular arcs. Have you considered this construction?

Comment: Tried the cube with analog procedure, which has yields a noticeable concave shell in places.  http://i.imgur.com/VHAtI7u.png

Comment: @Rahul as shown in the cube case the tetrahedral cone intersections are also slightly concave. The initial motivation was not to create a perfectly smooth, surface but an easy to construct to and project to one, so small changes in curvature are tolerable, otherwise a Ricci flow Hyperbolic one seems a more promising candidate to be able to be reprojected into a flat tetrahedron net, with minimum local rate of change in distortion. https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Geometry/Geometry.html

Comment: Well, my suggestion would yield a convex shape, if that's something you care about. On the other hand the hyperbolic tetrahedron seems like the *opposite* of an inflated tetrahedron -- it looks deflated, and is a worse approximation to a sphere, so I don't know why that's what you prefer. Oh well, it's your question.

Comment: If you're collecting similar-looking shapes, the central piece of [Cayley's cubic surface](http://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces/cayley/cayley.shtml), (which can be described by $\begin{vmatrix}1&z&y\\z&1&x\\y&x&1\end{vmatrix}=0$) is another one. Like your shape, it also contains six straight lines along the edges of a tetrahedron.

Comment: How did i miss that one, I even remember those old SuSE covers.

https://lizards.opensuse.org/2011/05/03/vintage/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the object is $Type -D- Coxeter-associahedra$.
http://www.math.uakron.edu/~sf34/kpd_poly.gif